# set category page as default list page in magento 2

Tags: category, magento-2.1

In `Magento 1.x` we can set category page as default list page by adding below coding into `local.xml` file

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
<action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
<limit>all</limit><label>All</label>
</action>
<action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
<limit>all</limit>
<label>All</label>
</action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>16</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
<mode>grid</mode>
<limit>all</limit>
<label>All</label>
</action>
</block>
</reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

In `Magento 2.x` Is there any option to change default page style as `list` page instead of `Grid` style.

[image]

Comment: You can change it from admin.

Comment: @SHPatel Path Plz..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set below product list mode from admin.

> "Grid Only"
>
> "List Only"
>
> "Grid (default) / List"
>
> "List (default) / Grid"

```
Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog >> Storefront >> List Mode.
```

Comment: By far, the easiest way of doing it.